# Get instant Combat Advantage when attacking adjacent with crossbow?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, rogue

There's a 4E feat called **Opportunity Knocks** found in Martial Power 2. It causes an enemy to grant combat advantage until the end of your next turn when they miss you with an opportunity attack.

Is it correct that with this feat I could

- attack an enemy adjacent to my rogue with my crossbow,
- the enemy gets an Attack of Opportunity
- misses because of my really high defenses against AoOs and
- because the AoO is interrupting my attack, I gain Combat Advantage before my attack takes place

so I can deal Sneak Attack Damage to the foe?

Comment: This seems like a rather dangerous way to get Combat Advantage...it's not like there's any shortage of ways to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you get missed, yes. There is nothing wrong on this combo.

It is risky because even if you get a high AC value, it is possible that either the opponent rolls a natural 20 (which [always hit](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=158)), or that its basic attack do not hit against AC, like someone with the [Deft Blade](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2490), [Deft Aim](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2675) or [Impaling Spear](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2504) feats, or simply using a non-weapon basic attack like [Vampire Slam](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13852). There are some basic attacks that also don't hit against AC, like [Storm Hammer](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12635).

[EDIT] After seeing the trick in action before, the enemy can also simply choose to not perform an AoO against you.

Comment: Thank you :)

I have 37 AC, 33 Reflex, 25 Fort and 33 Will against AoCs with my level 11 rogue.

Nearly always I have concealment from my hybrid Warlock and if everything fails, I have two interrupts.

I won't need this 'exploit' very often so I think I can take the risk.

Comment: @BlackEye Just so you're aware, you can't use an Immediate action on your own turn, so the Interrupts are irrelevant in regards to OAs you provoke.

Comment: @MikeKellogg unless they are free action or no action, like the racial Halfling power.

Comment: @Nibelung "Interrupt" usually implies "Immediate Interrupt," but I suppose not always, so fair enough.

Comment: @Mike Kellogg. Good point. I don't know why I imagined taking immediate actions on my own turn.